# How to hook Apple's `os_log_with_type` method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native, react-hooks

I want to hook "React Native" `RCTLog` logs method `_RCTLogJavaScriptInternal` , The source codes is:

```
void _RCTLogJavaScriptInternal(RCTLogLevel level, NSString *message)
{
  RCTLogFunction logFunction = RCTGetLocalLogFunction();
  BOOL log = RCT_DEBUG || (logFunction != nil);
  if (log && level >= RCTGetLogThreshold()) {
    if (logFunction) {
      logFunction(level, RCTLogSourceJavaScript, nil, nil, message);
    }
  }
}

RCTLogFunction RCTDefaultLogFunction =
    ^(RCTLogLevel level,
      RCTLogSource source,
      __unused NSString *fileName,
      __unused NSNumber *lineNumber,
      NSString *message) {
      os_log_with_type(RCTLogForLogSource(source), RCTLogTypeForLogLevel(level), "%{public}s", message.UTF8String);
    };
```

So if I just hook Apple's `os_log_with_type`, I will get the `RCTLog` logs.
This is my codes, but not working. Please help me. Thanks!!!!

```
#import <os/log.h>
#import "fishhook.h"

static void (*original_oslog)((os_log_t log, os_log_type_t type, const char *format, ...));

void hook_oslog(os_log_t log, os_log_type_t type, const char *format, ...) {
    NSLog(@"hook success!");
}

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct rebinding oslog_rebinding = { "os_log_with_type", hook_oslog, (void *)&original_oslog };
        rebind_symbols((struct rebinding[1]){oslog_rebinding}, 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final, I found solution. Not need to hook, Related API have been provided by `React Native` already.

```
RCTSetLogFunction(^(RCTLogLevel level, RCTLogSource source, NSString *fileName, NSNumber *lineNumber, NSString *message) {
  NSLog(@"%@", message);
});
```